# How to inject specified implementation of interface in my ViewModel with Koin?

Tags: android, interface, android-viewmodel, koin

I have a interface that is implemented for differents classes like this:

```
interface Engine {
    fun getParts()
}

class Car : Engine {
    override fun getParts() {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
}

class Bus : Engine {
    override fun getParts() {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
}

class Bike : Engine {
    override fun getParts() {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
}
```

And i have a ViewModel thats similar to this:

```
class MyViewModel(
    private val engine: Engine
) : ViewModel() {

    init {
        getMotorType()
    }

    private fun getMotorType() {
        // do request and retrive the type: Car / Bus or Bike
    }

    private fun onSuccessGetMotorType() {
        engine.getParts()
    }
}
```

I'm currently using Koin for dependency injection, and i have something similar to this:

```
        factory<Engine> {
            (named("Car"))
            Car()
        }
        factory<Engine> {
            (named("Bus"))
            Bus()
        }
        factory<Engine> {
            (named("Bike"))
            Bike()
        }
```

I'm having difficulty to make it working.

I'm trying to get the parts for the result of the request. Eg: If the request returns me Car i want to use the Car implementation of the interface.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the implementation to be injected in your module as below

```
val myAppModule = module {
    viewModel {
        MyViewModel(get(named("Car"))) 
    }
}
```

and then

```
class MyViewModel(
    private val engine: Engine
) : ViewModel() {

    init {
        getMotorType()
    }

    private fun onSuccessGetMotorType() {
        engine.getParts()
    }
}
```

Comment: I think i was not clear. This ViewModel its supposed to have all types, so if the getMotorType fun returns me a bus when i call engine.getParts should return the bus parts. so i need a way to pass the qualifier after the request. The interface does not need to go in the constructor but have to be passed as DI.